# How to "auto size" ImageView elements such that they'll be spread uniformly on the screen?

Tags: android

I'm learning [this project](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals/tree/master/DroidCafePart1) in Android Studio. [According to the tutorial](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/en/Unit%202/41_p_use_keyboards,_input_controls,_alerts,_and_pi.html#task7intro) the design of `content_main.xml` should look like this.
[image]

where the images are spread uniformly on the screen. But in the design page on my computer it looks differently:
[image]

and also it is not fixed on the emulator: (Nexus 5X)
[image]

How can I fix it so the images will resized automatically according to the screen?

Comment: you have two options. Either to limit the width of imageview and resize your image according to that view. Or you need to decrease the image size itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to tell your image what size to be and make your layout responsive.

**For example, this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[15]" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[13]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Choose"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**will look like this:**

[image]

**Explanation on the layout:**

- `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25"` together with `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` is ment to make your images equal to 1/4 of your screen size (this will be responsive to all screen sizes) and also give your image `1:1` aspect ratio
- In order to vertically fit all your image into the screen, you can use [Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) as I did
- when you will use this layout change `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[15]"` with real image like `android:src="@drawable/donut_circle"` so you will also see it on your devices

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to use ConstraintLayout `Guidelines` and constraint views width and height to them or set fixed size using `layout_width` and `layout_height`.